# How does `new` create an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails `initializers`, I found the following line:

```
LineAdsClient = LineAds::AdsClient.new(api_key: LineAccessToken.order('created_at').last[:access_token])
```

I tried to look for `AdsClient` class in the workspace, but I could not find it.

How does this style of object creation work without declaring a class?

After creating an instance, we are using `LineAdsClient` like below:

```
def client
  @client ||= ::LineAdsClient
end
```

Comment: There should be a class. Try finding `LineAds`, that will eventually lead to `AdsClient`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean, "without declaring the class"? It is creating an instance of the `LineAds::AdsClient` class.

Comment: The class might be defined in another folder (e.g. `./lib` instead of `./app`), or by an included gem. Either way, the class definitely does exist (assuming the code works!); you must be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @sawa: I think it's "initializer", not "initialize"

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It was declared in a gem. Sorry I am new to rails.

Answer (score 4):

If you couldn't find the class, it doesn't mean there's no class. You just didn't find it (looked in the wrong place or other reasons).

If you're using Pry, try this in your rails console

```
show-source LineAds::AdsClient
# or 
show-source LineAds::AdsClient.new
```

It'll show you where it is defined.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. It was declared in a gem.